# What does __crt_va_arg do?

Tags: c, macros

I'm using this library called LibTIFF that's supposed to load TIFF files. Anyway all of a sudden it's started throwing access violation errors when I open an image and try to get the image width:

```
TIFFDirectory *td = &tif->tif_dir; // 'td' is the image
```

'td' is the image, and I've checked the fields in the debugger and they're all fine, and if I return td->td_imagewidth then there's no problem. The problem comes from the following line, instead of returning td->td_imagewidth it does this:

```
*va_arg(ap, uint16_t *) = td->td_imagewidth;
```

... with va_arg being a define for __crt_va_arg, and that being a define for:

```
#define __crt_va_arg(ap, t)                                               \
        ((sizeof(t) > sizeof(__int64) || (sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != 0) \
            ? **(t**)((ap += sizeof(__int64)) - sizeof(__int64))             \
            :  *(t* )((ap += sizeof(__int64)) - sizeof(__int64)))
```

I have no idea what this does. It just needs to return td->td_imagewidth but it does this. What does it do? Oh, and the signature of the function that this is in is:

```
static int _TIFFVGetField(TIFF *tif, uint32_t tag, va_list ap)
```

Edit: I found the problem, I the variable arguments I was supposed to pass in was a pointer to a value to be filled. It turns out the function called was dereferencing what I didn't pass in.

Comment: Anything beginning with double underscore is supposed to be internal to the compiler and library implementations (unless explicitly mentioned by the specifications). Whatever problem you have, the problem is likely in your own code, and not in the library nor the standard library where it manifests. If you want help with the problem, then please try to create a [mre] of *your* code, and show it to us.

Comment: *I have no idea what this does.* -- I bet that is how the `C` implementation performs its voodoo magic in implementing variable argument functions.  You probably are required to declare the proper variable type that matches what is to be expected, similar to how `printf` and the format specifier works and the argument list you give `printf`.

Comment: See the cppreference documentation of what [`va_arg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg) is.

Comment: It's the implementation of the vararg mechanism. As the Unix V6 source said, "you are not expected to understand this".

Comment: Believe that `__crt_va_arg` may be from MSVC vadefs.h and the sizeof test is an attempt to determine if `t` is a struct based on reading [this](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/issues/128) and [this](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/vadefs.h#L78-L80).

Comment: And `TIFFVGetField` returns a success/failure flag, not the value of the field. The value is stored through the pointer passed as argument.

Comment: Since libtiff is a `C` library, it is putting its entire trust in you to send the proper types to  `TIFFVGetField`, in other words, there is no type-safety.  If you give the wrong type, there is no way libtiff can detect this.  Probably this is why you are experiencing issues now.

Comment: Show us the call(s) to `TIFFGetField` please

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, jarmod was right, the value returned is the success or error code and I was supposed to pass a pointer to a uint16 and I passed nothing. It dereferenced the var_args I 'didn't' pass in. Wow, C is unforgiving.

Comment: C is just fully believing in you. It assumes you are doing the right thing. Don't let C down. See, how disappointed C was when you did not pass what you shall pass. ;)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm, still, how could it dereference the variable arguments if I didn't pass any arguments in? It's not like I passed in an invalid pointer.

Comment: it derefenced whatever was on the stack after your `tag` argument. Could be a local variable, could be a return address or frame pointer, who knows.

Comment: @Zebrafish -- *how could it dereference the variable arguments* -- That is exactly the point when it comes to `C` trusting what you are giving a varargs function.  In the libtiff code, it probably sees that you want to return an `x`, and assumes that you are passing a pointer to whatever type `x` is.  If you pass nothing, well, too bad, because libtiff believed you did pass something.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The thing va_list is the third argument, and I didn't pass anything in, I just left it ... empty , so how can the code in the function dereference anything since there's no address to dereference?

Comment: @Zebrafish *so how can the code in the function dereference anything* -- `int x[10]; x[10] = 0;`.  I can ask you "how can I access index 10 when the highest available index is 9?"  It is the same principal.  The libtiff code expected something to be there, and went ahead and did what it did.  Basically, you lied to libtiff, but libtiff being a `C` library has no idea you were not telling the truth.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh ok so the arguments are in a sequence in memory then, probably.

Comment: @Zebrafish Where the arguments are depends on the implementation.  The `__crt_va_arg` macro is what the implementation uses to implement variable arguments.  So yes, the arguments are somewhere in memory.  In `C`, variable argument functions, you (the caller) and the callee (in this case, the libtiff function) have an agreed contract as to what arguments and types are to be expected.  You broke the contract, and thus broke the program.  Again, no different than telling `printf` you are printing an int using `%d` in the format specifier and you actually don't give it an `int` to print.

Answer (score 0):

`__crt_va_arg` is just underlying implementation of the `va_arg`, which is specified by C standard. You can read more about it on the Internet, for example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg). Variadic arguments is standard feature of the C language. In general, in the most cases, you don't need to dig so deep into the C runtime library source code, but if you do it, expect to see many more things like this.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously that functions is expecting (at some position of the variable number of arguments) a pointer to a `uint16_t`, and acts by writing to that pointed variable.

A little bit like if it was

```c
static int TIFFGetField(TIFF *tif, uint32_t tag, uint16_t *val){
   // bla bla bla (something that deduces that it is imagewidth that is wanted)
   *val = td->td_imagewidth;
}
```

But it does this using variadic function. And that variadic function (`TiffGetField`) relies itself on a subfunction that is not a variadic function, but that requires a `va_list` as one of its arguments (a little bit like `vprintf` does): `_TiffVGetField`.

A simpler illustration: if I want to create a function that increases all variable whose pointer is passed to int, I could write this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void incrAll(int num, ...){
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, num);
   for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
      * (va_arg(ap, int *)) += 1;
   }
}
int main(){
   int x=1, y=2, z=3;
   incrAll(2, &x, &z);
   incrAll(3, &x, &y, &z);
   printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y , z);
}
```

And yes, God knows what happens if the number of passed pointers doesn't match `num`. That the point with variadic: we need a way to know the number and the types of arguments.

Except that in your example, it is a little bit more complicated, since job isn't done by the variadic function directly but by a subfunction

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void _incrAllV(va_list ap){
    * (va_arg(ap, int *)) += 1;
}

void incrAll(int num, ...){
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, num);
   for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
      _incrAllV(ap);
   }
}

int main(){
   int x=1, y=2, z=3;
   incrAll(2, &x, &z);
   incrAll(3, &x, &y, &z);
   printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y , z);
}
```

So, that is just a function that update a variable whose pointer was passed as argument. But complicated by the fact that it is a variadic function.

You are probably meant to call it like this (or some variant)

```
    uint16_t w, h;
    # Totally speculating on the name of the tags
    TiffGetField(tif, TiffTag_Width, &w, TiffTag_Height, &h);
```